# How to minimize apt source.list

Tags: apt, package-management

I think these lines can trim to few lines. So I need some advice.
How can I improve these sources.list?

apt/sources.list, Latest Debian release:

```
deb http://security.debian.org/ wheezy/updates main contrib
deb-src http://security.debian.org/ wheezy/updates main contrib
deb http://ftp.debian.org/ wheezy-updates main contrib
deb-src http://ftp.debian.org/ wheezy-updates main contrib
deb http://ftp.debian.org/debian/ wheezy main contrib non-free
deb-src http://ftp.debian.org/debian/ wheezy main contrib non-free
deb http://ftp.debian.org/debian sid main
```

Comment: "deb-src" means the sources of the software in the Debian repositories/archives. "deb" corresponds to the binaries. If you don't want the sources, you can remove the "deb-src" lines. The sid/unstable line also may not be useful for you. In general you cannot directly install binaries from unstable on wheezy.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "improve"? Do you want to remove unnecessary repositories or do you want the exact same list of repositories written in a more condensed way? There are things you can remove here, but if you want the same repos, this is as good as it gets as @Braiam pointed out.

Answer (score 2):

The structure of the sources.list doesn't benefit of "[minimization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minification_%28programming%29)". There's no actual gain on compressing the lines further. All repositories listed should have the following:

```
type [ options ] uri suite [component1] [component2] [...]
```

or the rfc822 format

```
Types: deb deb-src
URIs: http://example.com
Suites: stable testing
Sections: component1 component2
Description: short
 long long long
[option1]: [option1-value]
```

Your sources.list already benefits of the shortest valid method you can list sources. Of course, you can repeat the same line with different components, and treat them separatelly:

```
deb http://security.debian.org/ wheezy/updates main
deb http://security.debian.org/ wheezy/updates contrib
```

but for APT, that's equivalent to:

```
deb http://security.debian.org/ wheezy/updates main contrib
```

while being parsed.

> How can I improve these sources.list?

There's no room for "improve". As long as the file is valid APT won't complain.

Comment: You might want to explain that the OP can safely remove the `src` lines since those are only useful to install sources. Also, could you comment on the presence of a `sid` repository while the rest are `wheezy`? That sounds like a recipe for disaster.

Comment: @terdon "I think these lines can trim to few lines." he doesn't want to remove repositories, he wants a smaller file with the *same repositories*.

Comment: Ah, maybe. I understood that the OP wants to remove anything that's not needed. I left a comment, let's see if they answer. Still, isn't combining `sid` with `wheezy` like that a bad idea?